# Two Websites with the same administration Panel In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Requirement is to create two websites with wordpress :

- The official Website for Desktop . (www.mydomain.com)
- The Mobile Version . (m.mydomain.com)

What I want is to create another Website for the mobile version but with the same content or database (Posts - Categories - Pages - administration Panel .. ) .

So, What to do ?

Comment: Maybe better asked at [wordpress.se] because it's not really a specific a programming question.

Comment: Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

if your content is same it is better to use a responsive wordpress theme
that shows that content in diffrent appearance
having mobile content in  subdomain is very bad for your seo 
and there is no way for managing website in this way